# How to inspect custom cell or line magic code in a Jupyter notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

The Jupyter notebook version is 4.3.0, using Python 3.5.3. With:

```
%lsmagic
```

Some expected cell magics appear, such as:

```
%%time  %%timeit
```

and line magics:

```
%cd %bookmark
```

But also many that were custom-created. How would I inspect the code behind the custom cell magic (as to understand what it does and how, beyond the documentation that the contributors of the custom line/cell magic provided)? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the type of magics. For example, to get the source code file of a line magic `matplotlib`, you can use this:

```py
import sys
magic_obj   = get_ipython().magics_manager.lsmagic()['line']['matplotlib']
module_name = magic_obj.__self__.__class__.__module__
print(sys.modules[module_name].__file__)
```

For "cell magic" `time`:

```py
magic_obj   = get_ipython().magics_manager.lsmagic()['cell']['time']
module_name = magic_obj.__self__.__class__.__module__
print(sys.modules[module_name].__file__)
```

For the "cell magic" `bash`:

```py
magic_obj = get_ipython().magics_manager.lsmagic()['cell']['bash']
module_name = magic_obj.__module__
print(sys.modules[module_name].__file__)
```